# How do I find API User name inside extended API module code?

Tags: api, user-roles

I have extended out the Magento API so that I can intercept `sales_order.list` and not expose all orders to a third party API. This worked fine when only one service was using this API, now there is another 'consumer' of the `sales_order.list` and I need to differentiate between whom is logged in.

I would prefer to do this the proper Magento way, e.g. to find the API Username of the box accessing `sales_order.list`, at a push I could check remote IP address but that could change, hence authentication credentials are what I would prefer to check.

I have tried to look at if there is an equivalent of `admin/session` but could not find anything helpful.

EDIT:

Thanks to @Anna I was able to find a solution for this.

Observer:

```
public function setPartner(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    $user = $observer->getEvent()->getModel()->getData('username');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setPartner($user);

}
```

Then in my extended API code:

```
$partner = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getPartner();
Mage::log($partner);
```

This now pulls through the 'username' of my API user, so I can therefore block this user from certain things.

Interestingly, in API code land, I could not set a registry value in my observer to then pick up in my extended API code for sales_order.list.

I was stuck for a direction to look in for an answer, @Anna's answer gave me the direction I needed although not a complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I am not sure if there is any better solution, I found that there is an event dispatched in the `login` method of `Mage_Api_Model_User`.

The event is:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('api_user_authenticated', array(
    'model'    => $this,
    'api_key'  => $apiKey,
));
```

You could observe this event, check the `api_key` and set a flag in `core/session` then.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That set me off in the right direction. I actually wanted the api username (or else I would be baking in the password into my code).

Comment: Cool! Happy you made it :)